# Streaming file to struct

Tags: c++

```
struct S {
char[10] bytes;
uint64_t t;
};


ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& ref, S& s){
  ref >> s.bytes;
  ref >> s.t;
return ref;
}
int main(){
S s;
ifstream file(/*OPEN STH*/);
file >> s;
};
```

The above code causes SIGESV error.

The below code doesn't causes SIGESV:

```
 struct S {
    char bytes; // only difference
    uint64_t t;
    };
     // .... (the same as above)
```

So we can see that the problem is when member bytes is an array of char. Why? How to solve that issue?

Comment: What are the contents of the file? Is the first "word" longer than 10 characters, by any chance?

Comment: Don't take care of it. Let's say that file has 1000 bytes.

Comment: Well, `ref >> s.bytes` exhibits undefined behavior (by way of buffer overrun) if there are more than 10 (or possibly 9) non-whitespace characters at the beginning of the file. Are you perhaps looking for `ref.read(s.bytes, 10);`? And are you aware that `ref >> s.t` expects *textual* representation of the integer? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, without you describing the format of the file you are trying to read.

Comment: The file I read is a binary file. So I suppose that when I  ref >> s.t  then s.t get 8 bytes from file. Am I right?

And second question:
I have no experience in commercial development so I don't know what is better solution. So: what is better:
To use read function to read file or use stream operators like operator>>?

Comment: `The file I read is a binary file` In this case, don't use formatted input operators - they interpret file content as text. `ref >> s.t then s.t get 8 bytes from file. Am I right? ` You are wrong. `So: what is better` The function that works is, of course, better than the function that doesn't. You need `read()` for a binary file.

Comment: Thanks for your time :)
1. "You are wrong." Why? I tested it and it works. 
2.  Can I use read to "put" bytes to stucture? ( I know format of file ( file has headers like PE)

Comment: `I tested it and it works` Then your file is not in fact a binary file; or else you are misinterpreting the outcome of your test. As to #2, I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: You are right! I misunderstood outcomes. Thanks a lot! :)